# Netbeans can't open project as java.lang.IllegalArgumentException exception has occurred

Tags: java, exception, netbeans, illegalargumentexception

The problem I've faced is: When I try to Open Project in my Netbeans 13, and the only thing it did is returned an error message:

> A java.lang.IllegalArgumentException exception has occurred.
> Please report this at https://netbeans.apache.org/nb/report-issue,
> including a copy of your messages.log file as an attachment.

This is IDE Log for this error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeHi(ComparableTimSort.java:866)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeAt(ComparableTimSort.java:483)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeForceCollapse(ComparableTimSort.java:422)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:222)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1246)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2.get(Win32ShellFolderManager2.java:282)
    at sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder.get(ShellFolder.java:258)
    at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI$DirectoryComboBoxModel.addItem(MetalFileChooserUI.java:942)
    at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI$DirectoryComboBoxModel.access$800(MetalFileChooserUI.java:910)
    at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI.doDirectoryChanged(MetalFileChooserUI.java:659)
    at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI.access$1100(MetalFileChooserUI.java:53)
    at javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI$5.propertyChange(MetalFileChooserUI.java:748)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:335)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:327)
    at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:263)
    at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Component.java:8434)
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(JFileChooser.java:598)
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.<init>(JFileChooser.java:344)
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.<init>(JFileChooser.java:296)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.ProjectChooserAccessory$ProjectFileChooser.<init>(ProjectChooserAccessory.java:507)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.ProjectChooserAccessory$ProjectFileChooser.<init>(ProjectChooserAccessory.java:507)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.ProjectChooserAccessory.createProjectChooser(ProjectChooserAccessory.java:442)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.actions.OpenProject.actionPerformed(OpenProject.java:61)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:136)
[catch] at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I googled a lot but not found any solving for this problem.

My Netbeans can Create New Project normally, the error message just show when I try to browse the file (like Open Project, Browse...). The popup for choosing file doesn't show. The Java version I am using is JDK 8, I also try install JDK 11 but the problem still there.

Update: This is stack trace when I use JDK 11:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
    at java.base/java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeHi(ComparableTimSort.java:870)
    at java.base/java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeAt(ComparableTimSort.java:487)
    at java.base/java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeForceCollapse(ComparableTimSort.java:426)
    at java.base/java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:222)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1249)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2.get(Win32ShellFolderManager2.java:313)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder.get(ShellFolder.java:259)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI$DirectoryComboBoxModel.addItem(MetalFileChooserUI.java:1029)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI.doDirectoryChanged(MetalFileChooserUI.java:717)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI$5.propertyChange(MetalFileChooserUI.java:806)
    at java.desktop/java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:341)
    at java.desktop/java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:333)
    at java.desktop/java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:266)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Component.java:8731)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(JFileChooser.java:608)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFileChooser.<init>(JFileChooser.java:362)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFileChooser.<init>(JFileChooser.java:308)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.ProjectChooserAccessory$ProjectFileChooser.<init>(ProjectChooserAccessory.java:507)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.ProjectChooserAccessory$ProjectFileChooser.<init>(ProjectChooserAccessory.java:507)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.ProjectChooserAccessory.createProjectChooser(ProjectChooserAccessory.java:442)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.actions.OpenProject.actionPerformed(OpenProject.java:61)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:297)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:297)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6635)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6400)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5011)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:136)
[catch] at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

This is visualize for my problem I am facing:
[Netbeans doesn't show popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mont0.png)

Comment: This _might_ be a JDK issue with Win32ShellFolderManager2. Update your question to state the exact JDK version that you are using. You can get that from the **Help > About** screen. If you are running with JDK 8, note that [NetBeans 13 does not support its use](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb13/nb13.html), and you should upgrade to JDK 11 or greater. If you are running on a valid JDK then you might try using the most recent update to see if that helps. Also try to create/run a trivial new "Hello World" Java project, and update your question to state whether that works or not.

Comment: Thank @skomisa, I've just updated my question. The problem still there.

Comment: OK. [1] Any problems using JDK 8 are irrelevant since its use is unsupported. Is the stack trace in your question for JDK 11? If not, please update, and also include any associated error messages in the log before the stack trace. [2] Is the issue specific to just one project, or do you get this problem with every existing project, including non-Swing projects? [3] Do you also get this problem if you create a new non-Swing project using JDK 11?

Comment: Hey, thank you so much. I have included stack trace for my question.